# web api method to return data in json format?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am making a web api call and I want the controller method to return data in json format.

The model class I used is User.cs :

```
public partial class User
{
     public int UserID { get; set; }
     public string city { get; set; }
     public string email { get; set; }
     public string firstName { get; set; }
     public string lastName { get; set; }
     public string phone { get; set; }
     public string password { get; set; }
 }
```

I want to return all the users email data in json format through the following controller method.

```
public string GetUsers()
{
   IEnumerable<User> users = db.Users.ToList();
   var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(users);
   return json;
   //string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users);
   //return json;
}
```

All I am getting is empty json like:

```
[]
```

Please help. I have covered all the methods recommended on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

This is a lot simpler than you think, you do not need to use a jsonSerializer.

You can change your method to the following:

```
public List<string> GetEmails()
{
    return db.Users.Select(e => e.email).ToList();
}
```

Then if the client specifies `application/json` the content is returned as json.

Please note with the above, I am ***only*** sending back the email address and not the ***full*** user details as I very much doubt you will want to send passwords out as json.

Comment: your code wont work. you create an object with an email property but try to return it as a string. Either just `.Select()` the email or change the return type to `List<object>`

Comment: @jgauffin Good point, I originally had it like above but changed it. Updated now, thanks.

Comment: you still returned an object. corrected it for you ;) Either way a +1 for the explanation why it works (and how).

Comment: @jgauffin Thanks again, that will teach me for trying to answer without testing first. Too worried someone beats me to the answer. :)

Comment: what if I want to call my api like api/user to show me the firstName and email of all users in json format.

Comment: @smriti Simply create a trimmed down c# class with just those properties say `FirstNameEmail` as an example, then change the return type from `List<string>` to `List<FirstNameEmail>`. Then change the select to be something like this:  `return db.Users.Select(e => new FirstNameEmail { FirstName= e.firstName, Email = e.email }).ToList();` :)